# create a distribution file for downloading with wget at github - no git needed

Tags: github, wget

I'd like users to be able to issue something like:

wget https://nodeload.github.com/opensas/play-demo/zipball/master/opensas-play-demo-bb3a405.zip

without having to clone the whole repo, nor browsing to github to manually download it

apparently, github issues some kind of redirect when accessing:

https://nodeload.github.com/opensas/play-demo/zipball/master

and it just downloads some binary file instead...

is there some easy way to achieve it???

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the asnwer

I made a distribution zip file

Uploaded it with "add new download" option

and now I have the following url to get it:

https://github.com/downloads/opensas/play-demo/play-demo-at-jugar-2011_09_29.zip